# netbeans custom jax-ws stubs

Tags: java, netbeans, jax-ws, netbeans-6.9

I am using netbeans 6.9. I have made a JAX-WS service that returns a complex type, I have also made a JAX-WS client to consume it. 
The JAX-WS system automaticly creates a class for the client, inferred from the WSDl spec. I want to make my own class for this using JAXB annotations, so that I can add some extra functions to it.

How do I go about replacing the autogenerated file with my own one? Could I also use the same class in the service to control how it is transmitted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why replace the generated class? 
From your description, it sounds like a good case for using the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

I have done this on a JAX-RPC project, and it worked very well.